In MySQL, is a leftmost prefix of a composite index just as performant as an non-composite index?
MySQL's documentation says:

If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

However, I want to know if there's any performance penalty for using this feature. Suppose I have a large table that stores when a user sees a comment:
CREATE TABLE `comment_views` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `comment_views_comment_id_user_id_unique` (`comment_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `comment_views_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `comment_views_comment_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`comment_id`) REFERENCES `comments` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `comment_views_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38821916 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

By specifying a composite key on (comment_id, user_id), and a non-composite key on user_id, I am covered to search by comment_id using the leftmost prefix rule. However, if there was an explicit key on just comment_id, would lookups that just specify comment_id (i.e. SELECT * FROM comment_views WHERE comment_id = 123) be faster?
Does that answer change if the composite key wasn't unique, the column is a string, or if the column is nullable? How about if I am instead using a range, join, dependent subquery, covering index query, or some other index access?
I tried running EXPLAIN with and without the extra index, and the explain didn't change other than the possible_keys showing my new index. In fact, it seemed like the EXPLAIN preferred the composite key. Maybe because it was first in the table definition or it just prefers a unique key (even though the leftmost prefix isn't unique). I don't know. I was unable to find more information on how MySQL actually achieves using the leftmost prefix under the hood.

the index will require more storage, which will require reading more data per index row that is read.  that's often not a big deal.  note that innodb now implicitly adds the primary key to every index, so every index is essentially a composite index.  always favor looking at actual benchmarks over explain

Indexes are B-trees. When you search for a prefix, it means it can stop searching at that level of the tree. This is exactly the same as what happens when you search a single-column index. So there shouldn't be a significant performance difference.

There's a performance penalty on using wider indexes with narrower predicates; that is, for the predicate WHERE a = 100 and b = 200 over the index (a, b, c, d). That penalty is minimal when using equality searches, but can be higher for range scans (for predicates that use <. >, BETWEEN, etc.), specially when the cardinalities of c and/or d are high.

The difference is so minor as to be ignorable.
Debating points:

col1 INT, col2 INT -- once the index pages are cached, they are readily available for queries needing either INDEX(col1) or INDEX(col1 col2).  This will sometimes be an advantage.
co11 INT, col2 VARCHAR(255) -- Now the composite index is bulk.  So when you need only col1, it could be slower.
col1 TINYINT, col2 ... -- If col1's cardinality is low (e.g., true/false), INDEX(col1) will probably never be used, but INDEX(col1, col2) could be quite useful.
INDEX(col1), INDEX(col1, col2) obviously takes more disk space.

Other notes:

Very rarely is BIGINT needed.  For example, might you really have 2 billion users?
Is id really needed?  Or would PRIMARY KEY(user_id, comment_id) suffice?  (Or the opposite order.)  That may help for several reasons.
Declaring a FOREIGN KEY will create an INDEX if needed.  So, create the composite indexes before declaring the FKs.
We need to see the queries to make further suggestions.


Great points. I'll definitely make considerations when part of a composite index has low cardinality, varchar, or I plan on frequent range-based scans, but it looks like for the most part I won't duplicate the leftmost index.
As for the other notes, the opinions of our backend framework (Laravel) shape that. BigInt is what they use for id, Models can't have composite primary keys, etc. The queries haven't been made yet. I'm looking more for general purpose guidelines as I design the database schema :)

@jgawrych - General purpose guidelines: Index Cookbook
